# Counting: In how many ways can you order your coffee, given the options at a coffee shop.

Tags: combinatorics

I came across this elementary counting problem: A coffee shop has 4 different types of coffee. You can order your coffee in a small, medium, or large cup. You can also choose whether you want to add cream, sugar, or milk (any combination is possible, for example, you can choose to add all three). In how many ways can you order your coffee?

My attempt:
$4*3*2^3$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: As a small nitpick, use `\cdot` or `\times` for multiplication when typesetting rather than `*`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you're correct!  There are $4\cdot 3\cdot 2^3$ ways to order your coffee.  Four options for coffee, three options for size. And the $2^3$ factor reflects your knowledge that there are two options "yay" or "nay" for each of cream, sugar, or milk: $2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 2^3.$ And by the rule of the product, you get $4\cdot 3 \cdot 2^3 = 96$ ways to order your coffee.

Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that is the answer. You have four options for coffee, three options for size, two options for cream, two options for sugar, and two options for milk, and you have to pick one option for each of these five choices. This does indeed give $$4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$$